# How to return Json Object in mvc view using JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I've Json Method in my website that return json from Linq query this query represent Products
gallery
but i'm new on json mvc how to return the object Content to show in my view
this is my View :

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Search";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutSearch.cshtml";
}

<div id="all-products">
<li>
    <figcaption>
        <label id="fabricName">HERE FABRIC NAME</label>
 <a class="more" href="HERE THE ID So I CAN Pass TO ACTION To other VIEW with D")">More
       <img src="../../Admin/images/mroe.png" alt="" /></a></figcaption>
    <img  src="HERE I WANT TO Pass Image as String Name" alt="image 1" />
</li>      
</div>
```

and this is in my Controller the return json Method

```
 public JsonResult GetSearch()
    {
        var getall = (
                     from b in db.ProductFabrics

                     select new {b.Id , b.En_FabricName,b.Image }).ToList();

        return Json(getall, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ehsan Sajjad said, you need AJAX call or jquery "getJSON", is the same:

```
var url = '@Url.Action("GetSearch","ControllerName")'

            $.getJSON(url,
                        function (result) {
                            if (result.length) {
                                for (i in result) {
                                    var result = result[i];
                                    //En_FabricName is the column retrieved
                                    $("#fabricName").append(result.En_FabricName);
                                }
                            }
                        });
```

Normally I use this method and works everytime. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

you need to send ajax call to get JSON:

```
$.ajax({
dataType: "json",
url: '@Url.Action("GetSearch","ControllerName")',

success: function(data){

$.each(data,function(index,item){

console.log(item);

})

}
});
```